# R Programming basic interpolation

Tags: r

A have a DataFrame called TideModel which has the following columns and sample data.

Basically it consists of Tide data every miute and Atmospheric Pressure every 5. I would like to interpolate and output Atmospheric Pressure every minute in a new column, called say AtmP new.

Taking an average of 9 rows seems to be the way forward but i cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried approx and colMeans.

```
Time   Tide   AtmP
00:00   0.51 1010.75
00:01   0.52      NA
00:02   0.52      NA
00:03   0.52      NA
00:04   0.52      NA
00:05   0.52      NA
00:06   0.52 1010.25
00:07   0.52      NA
00:08   0.52      NA
00:09   0.52      NA
00:10   0.53      NA
00:11   0.53      NA
00:12   0.53 1010.45
00:13   0.53      NA
00:14   0.53      NA
00:15   0.53      NA
00:16   0.54      NA
00:17   0.54      NA
00:18   0.54 1010.55
```

I have played around with approx and colMeans but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please show what the desired output would be, "Taking an average of 9 rows" seems vague and unclear

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Use `na.spline` (for spline interpoloation) or `na.approx` (for linear interpolation) or `na.locf` (to carry the last non-NA forward). All are in the zoo package.  We show `na.spline` below but you can substitute either of the ones just listed if you prefer. See that package for these and other na.* routines.  (Note at the end shows input in reproducible form.)

```
library(zoo)
transform(TideModel, AtmP = na.spline(AtmP))
```

giving:

```
    Time Tide     AtmP
1  00:00 0.51 1010.750
2  00:01 0.52 1010.584
3  00:02 0.52 1010.456
4  00:03 0.52 1010.362
5  00:04 0.52 1010.299
6  00:05 0.52 1010.263
7  00:06 0.52 1010.250
8  00:07 0.52 1010.256
9  00:08 0.52 1010.278
10 00:09 0.52 1010.312
11 00:10 0.53 1010.355
12 00:11 0.53 1010.402
13 00:12 0.53 1010.450
14 00:13 0.53 1010.495
15 00:14 0.53 1010.534
16 00:15 0.53 1010.562
17 00:16 0.54 1010.577
18 00:17 0.54 1010.574
19 00:18 0.54 1010.550
```

**2)** If you want to replace each NA with the mean of the 9 rows around it then:

```
library(zoo)

transform(TideModel, 
  AtmP = ifelse(is.na(AtmP), 
           rollapply(AtmP, 9, mean, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE), 
           AtmP)
)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Time   Tide   AtmP
00:00   0.51 1010.75
00:01   0.52      NA
00:02   0.52      NA
00:03   0.52      NA
00:04   0.52      NA
00:05   0.52      NA
00:06   0.52 1010.25
00:07   0.52      NA
00:08   0.52      NA
00:09   0.52      NA
00:10   0.53      NA
00:11   0.53      NA
00:12   0.53 1010.45
00:13   0.53      NA
00:14   0.53      NA
00:15   0.53      NA
00:16   0.54      NA
00:17   0.54      NA
00:18   0.54 1010.55"
TideModel <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `na.interp()` function from the `forecast` package. `na.interp()` replaces missing values with interpolated values. And it can also interpolate seasonal data.
As quoted from its documentation;

> By default, uses linear interpolation for non-seasonal series. For seasonal series, a robust STL decomposition is first computed. Then a linear interpolation is applied to the seasonally adjusted data, and the seasonal component is added back.

`na.interp()` can't deal with dataframes directly. You will have to convert your data into a time series object (ts or msts objects. msts stands for multiseasonal time series; a time series that has multiple seasonality, e.g. hourly seasonality & weekly seasonality).

The code would be something like below. This is a generic code to understand the idea, it's not tailored to your data.

```
library(forecast)
my_msts <- df['A'] %>% 
 msts() %>%
 na.interp()
```